# Running javascript in page that is loaded with jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function that loads parts of other pages into my div #ajaxloadconent, here is the function:

```
$('#ajaxloadcontent').load(url+' #ajaxloadcontent');
```

However, the problem is that I am unable to run javascript on the page that I load, while using this function.  I simply want to run this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.title = 'PearlSquirrel About';
</script>
```

When the data is loaded through .load().  The script is contained on the page that I load, so I do not want to modify the .load() function that I use.  If anyone knows how to fix this, then help would be greatly appreciated.  I can also provide further information if necessary.

Comment: Is the javascript located inside of the `#ajaxloadcontent` element?

Comment: Yes, it is.  It is located directly after the div is set.

Comment: directly after is not the same as inside. If it is after, it will not be pulled in.

Comment: What I meant to say is that it is inside the set div, so yes it is inside.  I have made sure of that.

Comment: i would go with Eran's answer and move to using `$.ajax` to give you more control over it. simply replace his `alert(data)` with `$(data).find("#ajaxloadedcontent").appendTo("#ajaxloadcontent")`. replace `.find` with `.filter` if `#ajaxloadedcontent` is a direct child of the body or if it is the only html in the document.

Comment: That still does not seem to work and the javascript still does not process properly.

Comment: @Eggo - check this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212532/safari-and-chrome-doesnt-evaluate-dynamically-added-script-tag-at-page-load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(data) {
    //Do something with the data e.g.
    $(data).find("#ajaxloadedcontent").appendTo("#ajaxloadcontent");
  }
});
```

from the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> "html": Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated
>   when inserted in the DOM.

Or you can use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript if you seperate your script to a standalone js file

Comment: I was able to implement this code, along with other snippets, to make it work; thanks for the help.