# .load() jQuery with div selector causing <script> to be overlooked

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I am trying to load in content with ajax jQuery and here is my script:

```
$('#ajaxloadcontent').load(url+' #ajaxloadcontent');
```

I've done some research and learned that when a specific selector is used for a .load() function, #ajaxloadcontent, that s on that page that is being loaded in are overlooked.  I have tried everything to try and fix this error and have been browsing the StackOverflow community for hours, with no success.  Obviously, I need my script to be able to recognize  as it is a vital part to my site.  Any help would be greatly appreciated as I can not continue the development of my site until I get this issue fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: do you have ajaxloadcontent in both the pages ? Calle and caller ?

Comment: Yes, I do; it is in both pages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running javascript in page that is loaded with jQuery Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627180/running-javascript-in-page-that-is-loaded-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: minor detail (won't answer your question), you might want to change the id to a different id.  There should not be two IDs on the same document.

Comment: Please do not post te same question twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.load()` strips out any `<script>` elements automatically. You'll have to look for an alternate solution, perhaps something like [`.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).

Comment: So I still use .load() and then use .getscript on the page that I am loading into #ajaxloadcontent?

Comment: @Eggo: Yeah, that would be one way of doing it.

Comment: My question is that don't I have to include the .getscript in script tags?  So wouldn't it be overlooked and have the same problem as my previous scripts?

Comment: Well you'd want to put the `.getScript()` call in the same JS file that you're attempting to load external HTML from. If you do that, what you're worried about shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I was able to implement this method.  Thank you very much for the help.