# Running javascript in loaded page with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I read in another thread that I will be able to put javascript codes in page y and it will work in page x when loaded with ajax.
I didnt get an error but it did not work either.

[Running javascript in page that is loaded with jQuery Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627180/running-javascript-in-page-that-is-loaded-with-jquery-ajax)

```
    $(function CheckinMap() {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "html",
            url: "content/home/index.cs.asp?Process=ViewCheckinMap",
            success: function(data) {
                //$("#friends").html(data);
                $("#checkinmap").append(data);

            },
            error: function (data) {
                $("#checkinmap").append(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Is the javascript already on the page when you call make the ajax request? Or is the javascript returned inside of `data`?

Comment: Make sure your `url` is right and the element `id` too, also check the JS in your destination file. Check for any errors in your console, and are you running it on a local server?

Comment: which is the script in question here?

Comment: codes that I put in my message.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).  This will load all the JS, instead of adding it to the page as dead text.

Comment: Yes.  Append only works with HTML or jQuery elements (http://api.jquery.com/append/).  Using `.load()` will parse the scripts, so long as you don't use a `#` tag (which you're not).  http://api.jquery.com/load/  Don't forget to accept/upvote if I helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getScript API: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Answer (score 0):

In the content that you are injecting via AJAX you can do an anonymous function call to have it execute after its added to the DOM

```
<script language="javascript">

(function doStuff(){ alert('hello, I was injected'); })();

</script>
```

That has worked for me in the past....